# Variable-length DBCS-graphic Fields in XSLT

Tags: xslt, stored-procedures, varchar, ibm-datapower, double-byte

I am trying to update a table including dbcs fields through a stored procedure. But I am getting an error while calling the sp.

**ERROR:CLI0109E String data right truncation. SQLSTATE:22001 {Row=1,Col=20}.**

In my process, I inquire a table using Store procedure which contains varchar field with DBCS data and I am moving this data to a variable in xslt and passing it on to another stored procedure where it's failing.

Can anyone let me know is there any encoding done in xslt part? Are these dbcs getting converted? How can it be handled?

note: dbcs are present inside  VARCHAR variable.

Comment: Please provide more info Better if you provide stored procedure

Comment: output field in first sp is defined as
OUT_variable                  VARCHAR(2352)  
this variable i am assigning to a xslt variable as shown below
<xsl:variable name="AddrSumm" select="$Spoutput/sql/parameter[25]"/>

this variable is passed to second sp where the its defined as

IN IN_variable      VARCHAR(2352)

data been passed through xslt  as shown below
 <argument type="SQL_VARCHAR" mode="INPUT" precision="2352" scale="0" nullable="false">            <xsl:value-of select="$AddrSumm"/>
but the second sp s failing with
ERROR:CLI0109E String data right truncation.

arameter[25]"/>

Comment: looks like the the second sp is not taking these data as dbcs.
sorry, sp is too long to post here